# xautoload not loading class

Tags: 7

I have a PHP class that I have developed to mediate the interactions with a client's SSO web service. The class needs to be used by both a Symfony site and a Drupal 7 site. On the Drupal side, I've dropped a copy of the class inside the SSO module I'm developing, and I'm attempting to use xautoload to load it, but I was getting a class not found error when attempting to instantiate an object from it.

Now I'm just dumping the output of get_declared_classes() to the message area with dpm(), and I don't see that it has loaded the class.

Here's the structure of my module

```
client_sso/
|
--client_sso.info
--client_sso.module
--includes
  |
  --ClientSSO.php
```

My client_sso.info looks like this

```
name = Client SSO
description = Integrate Drupal with Client SSO service
package = AARP
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = xautoload (>= 7.x-5.0)
files[] = includes/*.php
```

I disabled and re-enabled the module to rebuild the module registry and cleared all caches, but it appears to be cheerfully ignoring the file with the class.

I have verified that I can directly load the class with

```
module_load_include('php', 'client_sso', 'includes/ClientSSO');
```

What should I try next?

Comment: Is * even valid? I don't think I've ever seen that done in an info file. What if you just use the file name itself?

Comment: The wild card matching is a feature xautoload provides @Kevin, at first glance the OP's code should work I think

Comment: Is the ClientSSO in a namespace? Can you post a (reduced) version of the contents of ClientSSO.php?

Comment: I can add to my answer below if you provide more details. I would like to make it useful not just for you, but also for other visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to consider.

`*.php` only looks in the folder itself. `**/*.php` also looks in subdirectories recursively. This seems ok in this case, but I want to mention it for other visitors.

---

The `files[] = ..` always requires clearing the cache.
If you have problems with this, `drush rr` ([Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)) is useful.

---

The core class registry with `files[] = ..` does *not* work for classes in namespaces.
xautoload does not change this.

The [Registry Autoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_autoload) module makes namespaced classes work with the core registry. But I don't know how well it works with the `*.php`-style wildcards.

Or, you can use [hook_xautoload()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1976238) to register additional namespace directories.

Comment: I think you nailed it in your third option. The class is indeed a namespaced class. In the short term, I'll just abandon autoloading for this particular case. As an aside, I just found this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/1976206, which I assume you wrote, that would have probably clued me in earlier :-)

Comment: I actually read "Registry Autoload" as, use Registry Rebuild!, which worked for me. https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild